# How to publish messages with GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sockets, websocket

I used this plugin [GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) to integrate websockets in my application.

However through the documentation I didn't find how to push data into the channel once we've subscribed to it, from outide the "socket/connect" event:

```
webSocket.on("socket/connect", function(session){
      session.subscribe("acme/channel", function(uri, payload){

          console.log("Received message", payload.msg);


   session.publish("acme/channel", "This is a message!");
});
```

How can I use something like session.publish from outise the "socket/connect" callback function?

Note that I used the "default" [Topic Handler](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/TopicSetup.md).

Comment: hi. if you not find a solution you can try this approach to use webSockets   
http://devblog.lexik.fr/symfony2/notifications-via-websocket-avec-symfony2-et-node-js-2679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to create a global scope variable "sendMessage" and instantiate it with the nested function :

```
var sendMessage;

webSocket.on("socket/connect", function(session){
      session.subscribe("acme/channel", function(uri, payload){

          console.log("Received message", payload.msg);


   sendMessage = function(message){
        var myObject = {
         'content': message
       }
       session.publish("acme/channel", myObject);
      }
});
```

Then I just have to repeat sendMessage(message) whenever I want in my code to publish messages.